# How to take values initiated in an if else statement to be used outside the statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

hello I'm a newbie and I am having a hard time doing this program. I was wondering if there is any work around to get the value in the else statement be used outside the statement itself or any other way for this to work. The program is suppose to stop when there are 10 odd numbers in the array which i tried to do by putting it in a do while loop and assigning variable k to add 1 value if the the else statement detects an odd number but the value of k is only usable in the else statement.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num[] = new int[100];

        System.out.println("This program stops when 10 odd numbers are entered.");
        do {
            int j = 0;
            int k = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= num.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Please enter element " + i);
                num[j] = sc.nextInt();

                if (j % 2 == 0)
                    System.out.println("Entered number is even");
                else
                    k = k + 1;
            }
        } while (k != 11);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Th problem in your code is scope of the variable `k` which available only inside the do-while loop but the `while (k != 11);` is outside the loop.

So, you must declare the `k` outside the loop.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num[] = new int[100];

    int k = 0;

    System.out.println("This program stops when 10 odd numbers are entered.");
    do {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= num.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter element " + i);
            num[j] = sc.nextInt();

            if (j % 2 == 0)
                System.out.println("Entered number is even");
            else
                k = k + 1;
        }
    } while (k != 11);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `java` you can't access variables that were declared in an inner scope `{ }` from a parent scope. Which means that in this example:

```java
if(x==2) {
  int k = 10;
} else {
  int j = 300;
}
```

You can't access `k` nor `j`.

In your code, since `k` was declared in the `do while` scope, it **can** be accessed from the `if else` statement. The problem is that since `k` was declared in the `do while` scope, every time the `do` is executed your `k` redefined with value `0`.

The solution is to declare `k` in a parent scope i.e. the `main` scope:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num[] = new int[100];
        
        int k = 0;
        int j = 0;
        
        System.out.println("This program stops when 10 odd numbers are entered.");
        do {
            for (int i = 0; i <= num.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("Please enter element " + i);
                num[j] = sc.nextInt();

                if (num[j] % 2 == 0)
                    System.out.println("Entered number is even");
                else
                    k = k + 1;
                
                j = j + 1;
            }
        } while (k != 11);
    }
    
}
```

Also, I think that you forgot to increment your `j`, which is also will redefined in every `while`, and in the `if` statement you check if `j % 2 == 0` and not the actual number that came from the user. Good Luck !